# Setting a starting task in Windows Vista at certain times

Tags: windows-vista, scheduled-tasks

I want to ask of a way to set up a scheduled task of restarting a computer running 32 bit Windows Vista at specific times.

I found an article which answered how to restart using the task scheduler:
Answer: Copy and Paste the code in the selected answer to a text file.

shutdown -r -f -t 01

Save the file as a *.bat file. You can then select it in the Actions Tab of the Task Scheduler. Works like a charm.

edited Mar 6 '10 at 4:41
Jon Seigel
6,91221747

asked Feb 9 '09 at 19:14
discorax
7352924

Execute
    shutdown -r -f -t 01

will restart windows in 1 second.

Specifically what I need is a way to Windows restart itself at 1:00 pm and 11:00pm every Sunday and 10:00 pm every Wednesday.
Is this possible and if so how do I do it?

Comment: You just said that this method worked, so what is your question again?

Answer (score 0):

In Task Scheduler, you can add multiple triggers to launch the batch file. I would create 3 weekly repeating triggers: 1 for every Sunday at 1pm, 1 for every Sunday at 11pm and 1 for every Wednesday at 10pm. See if that works for you.